# creating a moustache.js html template using JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json, mustache

I just learned about moustache.js and i am attempting to create an HTML template.  However, the documentation is a bit hard to decipher.  I found a good site that explains partials (which I believe I will need).  I was hoping someone might be able to just 'get me started' on how I would need to do this.

I have a php file that I need to convert to the template:

PHP:

```
<div id='board'>
<?php
if ($threads)
    {
        $count = count($threads);
        $perpage = 17;
        $startlist = 3;
        $numpages = ceil($count / $perpage);
        if ($page == 'home') {$page = 1;}
        $threadstart = ($page * $perpage) - $perpage;
        $i = 0;
        echo "<table class='board'>
    <tr>
            <th width='5%'><img src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/category_icon.png' alt='category_icon'/></th>
            <th width='5%'>Tag</th>
            <th width='50%'>Subject</th>
            <th width='7.5%'>Author</th>
            <th width='7.5%'>Replies/Views</th> 
            <th width='15%'>Last Post</th>
    </tr>";
        foreach ($threads as $list) 
        {   $i++;
            $thread_owner = $this->thread_model->get_owner($list['owner_id']);
            $thread_id = $list['thread_id'];
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT f.tag FROM filter_thread AS ft
                                        INNER JOIN filter AS f ON ft.filter_id = f.filter_id
                                        WHERE thread_id = $thread_id");
            $result = $query->result_array();
            $trunc_body = $this->thread_model->get_reply_summary($thread_id);
            $filter = "";
            $filter2 ="";
            $ent = "entertainment";
            foreach ($result as $string)
            {
                if ($string['tag'] == $ent) {
                    $filter2 .= "<div id='entertainment'><p>";
                    $filter2 .= "<img src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/entertainment_icon.png' title='Entertainment' alt='Entertainment'/>";
                    $filter2 .= "</p></div>";
                } else {
                $filter2 .= "<div id='misc'><p>";
                $filter2 .= "<img src='".base_url()."img/board/icons/misc_icon.png' title='Misc' alt='Misc'/>";
                $filter2 .= "</p></div>";
                $filter .= " [".$string['tag']."]";
                }
            }
            if (!$result) { $filter = "" AND $filter2 =""; }
            if ($i > $threadstart AND $i <= $threadstart + $perpage) 
            { 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$filter2."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$filter."</td>";
                echo "<td title='".$trunc_body['0']['body']."'><a href=".base_url()."main/thread/".$list['slug'].">".ucfirst($list['subject'])."<div id='filter'><p></p></div></a></td>"; 
                echo "<td><p>".$thread_owner."</p></td>";
                echo "<td align='right'>Replies: ".$list['replies_num']."<br>Views: ".$list['views']."</td>";
                $owner = $this->thread_model->get_owner($list['last_post_id']);
                echo "<td>".$owner." <br>".$list['replystamp'] ."</td></tr>";   
            }  
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Current Page: $page | ";    
        echo "Page: ";

        for ($n = 1; $n < $numpages+1; $n++) 
        {
            echo "<a href=".base_url()."main/home/$n>$n</a> | ";
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

And here is the AJAX

```
$(function() {
    $('#all').addClass('ui-selected') 
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable({
        selected: updatefilters

    });   
    function updatefilters(ev, ui){
        // get the selected filters
        var template, html;
        var $selected = $('#selectable').children('.ui-selected');
        // create a string that has each filter separated by a pipe ("|")
        var filters = $selected.map(function(){return this.id;}).get().join("\|");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'updatefilters',
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: { filters: filters },
            success: function(data){
                var template = "<div id ='board'>TESTING{{#body}}<table>";
                var partials = "{{#subject}}";
                //for (i=0 ; i< data.length ; i++)
                //{html += "<tr><td>" + data[i].subject + "</td><td>" + data[i].body + "</td></tr>";}
                //html += "</table></div>";
                var html = Moustache.to.html(template, data, partials);
                $('#board').html(html); 
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Im not sure how to navigate through the JSON array with moustache..and as it is, it does not update the page, though the commented out parts DO.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you are receiving a json string you will need to to parse it (use `$.parseJSON(data)`)

Once you have the data parsed you need to loop throught the JSON attributes.

For example:

If JSON has the following: body: {content: [dataObj:{data:'a'}, dataObj[data:'b']]}

do

```
<div>{{#body}}<div>
<div>{{#content}}<div>
<div>{{#dataObj}}<div>
<span>{{data}}<span>
```

If you are using partial, you will need to call them inside the main template.

Check the moustache5 documentation, it has improved a lot.